# python3 DNS domain block script

Tags: string, python-3.x, dns, format, zone

I have a basic issue to solve, i am new to python and wish to use python3 to just grab input from a user and paste it into a specific location within a multi line string. I am not entirely sure on to achieve the specific location i am after.

What i have so far

```
new_domain = input("Ener domain you would like to block: ")

zone = """zone {} IN {{
            type master;
            file "zones/192.168.1.1.zone";
            allow-transfer { none; };
            allow-query { my-dmz; };
};
""".format(new_domain)
```

When i run the code

```
Error is "KeyError: ' none;'
```

Do i need to escape out of the multi line string to make the {} valid parameter to place the users input?

Once i get the output formatting correct i would like to paste in multiple domains for it to have this specific output per domain i enter.

So desired output would be

```
Enter domain you would like to block? test123.com

zone "test123.com" IN {{
            type master;
            file "zones/192.168.1.1.zone";
            allow-transfer { none; };
            allow-query { my-dmz; };
};
```

Thanks in advance to any help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after some help from elsewhere i have found the below code works for anyone else interested

```
new_domain = input("Ener domain you would like to block: ")

print("""zone "%s" IN {
                type master;
                file "zones/192.168.1.1.zone";
                allow-transfer { none; };
                allow-query { my-dmz; };
};""" % new_domain)
```

I needed to avoid using format markers in this {} as i would have to have weird escape characters everywhere. So instead the traditional formatting option of % was used. Seems to do the trick.

Now will work on placing this in a while loop and write entries to a file as i have hundreds of domains to add :)